# Regex : Matching a word containing characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match smileys, i.e :) , :(, :/,

Like in the below example

```
:/ http://x.com :/
```

, I want to match the first and last `:/` and not the one part of `http://x.com` . Had those been words, I could have use `\b` but here they won't work as far as I know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
(:[\/\)\(])(?=\s|$)
```

[RegexTester](https://regex101.com/r/hZ8gM2/1)

[image]

Comment: you don't have to escape the round bracktes inside a character class :)

Comment: What if there are smileys appear in the middle of string?

Comment: @brso05 This also matches those characters if they are at the end of a string. For eg : `:/ http:/ :/` . In this all the `:/` will be matched.

Answer (score 1):

The following pattern takes consideration of first and last smiley. Please try:

```
(:(?:\/|\)|\()).*(:(?:\/|\)|\())
```

[**REGEX 101 DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/yX1iI8/3)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`([ \t]|^)(\:\/)([ \t]|$)`
`[ \t]`  space or  tab